# E: Unable to locate package sublime-text 20.04

Tags: sublime-text

I am unable to install the sublime text on my Ubuntu machin 20.04, i followed the below commands, still not works for me.
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
OR
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update.
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: PPA's or *Personal Package Archive* rely on you performing all security checks, if you look at https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/sublime-text-3 it's pretty easy to detect no support for releases as new as 20.04 are given, given the PPA is no longer maintained.  Did you check?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options to install `sublime-text`.

**Option 1:**

Follow the instructions on the [official website](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/linux_repositories.html):

```
wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/sublimehq-archive.gpg > /dev/null

echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

**Option 2:**

`sublime-text` is available as a snap package and can be installed with

```
snap install sublime-text
```

You can get more details about this snap package with

```
$ snap info sublime-text
name:      sublime-text
summary:   A sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose.
publisher: Snapcrafters
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/sublime-text
contact:   https://github.com/snapcrafters/sublime-text/issues
license:   Proprietary
description: |
  Sublime Text is a powerful multi-platform text editor with a clean, modern user interface.
  Bringing wide support for programming languages, extensions, syntax-based features and many other
  useful features alongside low resource usage, Sublime Text proves itself to be a very competent
  solution for a vast set of environments and applications.
  The software may be downloaded and evaluated for free, however a license must be purchased for
  continued use.
  
    **Authors**
  
  This snap is maintained by the Snapcrafters community, and is not necessarily endorsed or
  officially maintained by the upstream developers.
snap-id: 2kOIsSRmQ7zjpIxzZDpoXaZOVejqaGOT
channels:
  latest/stable:    4143 2023-03-03 (118) 68MB classic
  latest/candidate: ↑                          
  latest/beta:      ↑                          
  latest/edge:      4143 2023-03-02 (118) 68MB classic
```

Comment: Option 1 eventually worked for me, but only on the third try.  No idea why it took 3 tries -- I did everything the same each time.